# Странный перенос текста в пустой очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, дизайн, очередь-проверок

В пустой очереди проверок довольно странный перенос текста:

> [image: Перенос текста]

Comment: Зарезервировано место под кнопки, наверное.

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде бы раньше такого не было. Я думаю, это связано со [свежими изменениями](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304101/339911).